# ColorBox popup not hitting code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I am using the [ColorBox jQuery plugin](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/), but I have run into a strange issue.  Below is my code:

```
<script>
            $("#spv14DL").colorbox({width: "500px",
                                 height:"500px" });
</script>
...
<a href="/popups/spv14.aspx" id="spv14DL">Open this popup!</a><br />
```

When I click on the link, everything opens as expected.  But when I click on a button that I have on my aspx page it never hits my code behind for `spv14.aspx` and it redirects to `baseUrl.com/spv14.aspx` instead of `baseUrl.com/popups/spv14.aspx` which causes a 404 error.

Am I doing something wrong that would cause this type of behavior?

Comment: try to add `iframe: true` to colorbox options

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy, that did it.  If you post that as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of that error is that by default colorbox plugin fetch content of referenced page with async `GET` request and put it into dialog container. So if you'll check page's markup when dialog opened you'll find that there is a contnt of referenced page with `form` element and all controls inside in dialog container. Also action attribute of that form refer to `spv14.aspx` page without any rooted path to it. Acually there are a few solutions exists. Let's examine them from the most hard to most simple:

1. You can change action attribute of `form` element of `spv14.aspx` page in such way: `action="\popups\spv14.aspx"`. Disadvantage of this solution that after post back action user will be redirected onto the popup page. This gap can be fixed with `Response.Redirect` method call in popup page's `PreRender` method if IsPostback property return `true` value: `if(IsPostBack) { Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(), false); }`. In my opinion this solution doesn't looks pretty good.
2. You can dismiss post back on submit button click in popup form and use async request to popup page static method passing in it all control's values those you need to perform action. I this way you can't use page's ViewState and controls properties in server code.
3. And the last but not the least solution is to show popup page with using inline frame in dialog element container with passing `iframe: true` option to colorbox plugin. This is the most effortless way to use all aspx page stuff in your dialog.

Conclusion: the third method with using `iframe` option is the most native and effortless solution available.

P.S. sorry for my english :)

Comment: I've heard worse ;)  Thanks for your help!